# Read from CSV file and make plot

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a little problem I hope someone could help me with. I'm not the best at python.

I have a "CSV" file that I have to manipulate. I have 3 questions I hope you could help with.

**1: Print the first two lines**

The first I think I done already, I printed the first two lines.

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint

data = open('iphonevsandroid.csv')

pprint (data.readlines(2))
f.close()
```

I getting data like this:

```
['week,iphone,android\n',
 '2004-01-04 - 2004-01-10,0,0\n',
 '2004-01-11 - 2004-01-17,0,0\n',
 '2004-01-18 - 2004-01-24,0,0\n',
 '2004-01-25 - 2004-01-31,0,0\n',
 '2004-02-01 - 2004-02-07,0,0\n',
 '2004-02-08 - 2004-02-14,0,0\n',
 '2004-02-15 - 2004-02-21,0,0\n',
 '2004-02-22 - 2004-02-28,0,0\n',
 '2004-02-29 - 2004-03-06,0,0\n',
 '2004-03-07 - 2004-03-13,0,0\n',
 '2004-03-14 - 2004-03-20,0,0\n',
```

**2: Parse the first field to convert it to a single date object (hint: use datetime.strptime). You can choose any of the two dates.**

```
import csv
import datatime

data = open('iphonevsandroid.csv')

reader1 = csv.reader1(data)

for row in reader1:
    print row[0]
```

This will print the first row we needed, but how do I get 1 of the dates? I have to plot it later.

Comment: Honestly I didn't get what you want at point 2 ??

Answer (score 0):

I would use the string.split method.

In your case, you can split by ' - '

So if:

```
row = ['week,iphone,android\n',
'2004-01-04 - 2004-01-10,0,0\n',
'2004-01-11 - 2004-01-17,0,0\n',
'2004-01-18 - 2004-01-24,0,0\n',
'2004-01-25 - 2004-01-31,0,0\n',
'2004-02-01 - 2004-02-07,0,0\n',
'2004-02-08 - 2004-02-14,0,0\n',
'2004-02-15 - 2004-02-21,0,0\n',
'2004-02-22 - 2004-02-28,0,0\n',
'2004-02-29 - 2004-03-06,0,0\n',
'2004-03-07 - 2004-03-13,0,0\n',
'2004-03-14 - 2004-03-20,0,0\n']
```

We can take the first time value as:

```
first_date_row = row[1]
    Output: '2004-01-04 - 2004-01-10,0,0\n'
```

You see that the first date is separated from the second one by ' - '.

so:

```
first_date = first_date_row.split(' - ')[0]
Output: '2004-01-04'
```

How do we get the second date? Well we can do a similar procedure than we did with the first date, but taking the first comma after the second date as the separator.

Thus:

```
second_date = first_date_row.split(' - ')[1].split(',')[0]
Output: '2004-01-10'
```

Please note, these dates are just text for Python, you will need to transform them into date objects. You could use in this case:

```
first_date_formated = datetime.strptime(first_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
second_date_formated = datetime.strptime(second_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: No problem... would you mind checking my answer as correct? I wouldn't mind getting some reputation :) 

(note: to mark it as an answer, press the check simbol below the upvote arrow)